# Is there a way to do a POST without using a <form> using Javascript inline or something similar?

Tags: javascript, html

My application is using the following code for logout.

It seems clumsy to have to include the button inside a form when there 
is just the one button field on the form:

```
<form action="/User/Account/LogOff" 
      method="post" 
      class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <div class="button" id="logout" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();" >Logout</div>
</form>
```

Is there a way that I can do the same thing as this but without having
to include everything inside of a `<form>` and without using jQuery or anything except very simple inline javascript ?

Comment: It's not clumsy, it's the right thing to do.  Trying to make the same thing but with JS would be clumsy. (You should even use an actual button instead of a div that acts like a button.)

Comment: Inline javascript is considered a bad practice, also why not use an actual `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` instead of a `<div>`?

Comment: I'm wondering why the downvote. Is this not a valid question ?

Comment: Or better yet use the submit input type - save the JS all together. To answer your question, there is a way to do it without a form and without jQuery - but its very sloppy, and is typically only used where there is no form to submit, i.e. the content is generated by javascript.

Comment: @Zack - Thanks for your suggestion. Can you put this as an answer so I can accept. I had a feeling this could be made simpler and you have pointed out why.

Comment: @Marilou With pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a div, you can use a submit button - save the JS all together.

To answer your question, there is a way to do it without a form and without jQuery - but its very sloppy, and is typically only used where there is no form to submit, i.e. the content is generated by javascript.

Comment: When I code an <input type=submit> Will that visually look like a button ?

Comment: in principle yes - it depends if you have css that is used specifically for an input button, also - it wont look like whatever your div looked like, unless you copy across the css rules for that div, onto the input field.

Comment: isn't the way to do it "without a form" to have javascript create a form and submit it?

Comment: That is one way, however if the content is not particularly form based, it is possible to use AJAX to post the data in, for example if you were playing a javascript game, you wouldnt want/need the overhead of creating a form, if you were trying to post the co-ordinates of a player on a map.